# Hide, overload or overwrite in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, member-hiding

Then I have a question again. something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout<<"Base."<<endl;
    }
};

class Derive:public Base
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout<<"Derive."<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derive d;
    Base *pb=&d;    //attention here
    pb->foo();      //ateention here
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is "Base.". Then the function rules are't work, I am confused about this, could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I thought compilers warn about hiding functions but at least g++ 7.3.0 doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `foo` is not virtual, the function called is based on the *static* type (i.e., the type the pointer is declared to point at) rather than the dynamic type (the type of object to which the pointer currently refers).

There are also some trickier cases to consider. One point (on which some of the other answers are actually somewhat misleading) is that it's not really just the function *name* that matters, but the entire function signature. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base { 
    virtual void foo() { 
        std::cout << "base::foo";
    }
};

struct derived : base { 
    virtual void foo() const { 
        std::cout << "derived::foo";
    }
};

int main(){ 
    base *b = new derived;

    b->foo();
}
```

Here `foo` is qualified as `virtual` in both the base and (seemingly redundantly the) derived classes, but the call `b->foo()` *still* prints out `base::foo`.

The `const` added to the signature of `derived::foo` means it no longer matches the signature of `base::foo`, so instead of overriding the virtual function, we still end up with two separate functions with the same name, so `derived::foo` hides `base::foo`, but doesn't override it. Despite the `virtual` qualification, we get static binding, so `b->foo();` invokes the base function rather than the derived, even though `b` points to an object of the `derived` type.

As Tony D pointed out in a comment, C++11 added a new wrinkle to the language to help ensure against this happening. When you want to override a base class function, you can add the identifier `override` to the function in the derived class:

```
struct derived : base {
     virtual void foo() const override {
         std::cout << "derived::foo";
     }
};
```

With this, if there's a difference in function signature (as in the cases shown here), the compiler will produce an error message alerting you to the fact that `derived::foo` is marked as `override`, but doesn't actually override a function from the base class. This was, however, added in C++11, so if you're using an older compiler this feature may not be implemented (though thankfully, compilers that don't implement it are quickly fading into oblivion).

Correcting the signature in the base class to:

```
virtual void foo() const // ...
```

...will let the code compile, and produce the correct results.

Comment: "Here foo is qualified as virtual in both the base and derived classes" - you're illustrating bad practice and a beginner reading this might think you mean to imply that being explicitly `virtual` in `derived` is somehow relevant here.  If you're going to address this issue it'd be good to recommend `override`.

Answer (score 2):

Function `Base::foo` is non-virtual. It is called because the pointer to the base class is used.

If you change the code like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void foo() // add virtual
    {
        cout<<"Base."<<endl;
    }
};
```

the output should be "*Derived*".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the function foo is not virtual, could you give me a more detail? thanks.

Comment: `foo` is just a regular function, so no overriding is supposed to take place.

Comment: I write the code on purpose and I want to see the output, But I don't under the output. Could explain for me?

Comment: @KevinWang if a method is not declared virtual, it will use the implementation of the static compile-time type of the pointer/reference, in this case you are using a `Base` pointer so you get the `Base` method. In virtual methods instead the correct overload for the item is determined dynamically, i.e. it will use the overload of the type used when creating the object.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the title of your question, I take it that you don't fully understand when functions get hidden, overloaded, and overwritten.

**Sample code 1:**

```
struct Base
{
   void foo()
   {
   }
};

struct Derive: public Base
{
   void foo()
   {
   }
};

int main()
{
   Derive d;
   Base *pb=&d;
   d.foo();    // Resolves to Derived::foo()
   pb->foo();  // Resolves to Base::foo()
   return 0;
}
```

Why does `d.foo()` call `Derived::foo()` and `pb->foo()` call `Base::foo()`?

The answer to that question lies in the steps the compiler takes to resolve those function bindings.

Given an object of type T and a function name `f`, the compiler looks up the functions named `f` in `T`. If it finds only one function named `f`, the search for functions stops there. If it finds more than one function, it attempts overload resolution from the set of functions found in `T`.

If it does not find any functions named `f` in `T` and `T` has a base class, it tries the above logic in `T`'s base class. If `T` does not have any base classes, the compiler reports an error.

Coming to the objects of the example code...

When processing the function call `d.foo()`, the compiler looks for `foo` in `Derived`. It finds one match there and it stops. Since the `Derived::foo()` is not a `virtual` function, the binding is done at compile time. At run time, `Derived::foo()` is called.

When processing the function call `pb->foo()`, the compiler looks for `foo` in `Base`. It finds one match there and it stops. Since the `Base::foo()` is not a `virtual` function, the binding is done at compile time. At run time, `Base::foo()` is called.

**Sample code 2:**

```
struct Base
{
   void foo(int i)
   {
   }
};

struct Derive: public Base
{
   void foo()
   {
   }
};

int main()
{
   Derive d;
   Base *pb=&d;
   d.foo();      // Resolves to Derived::foo()
   d.foo(10);    // Compiler error.

   pb->foo(10);  // Resolves to Base::foo(int)
   pb->foo();    // Compiler error.
   return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler produces the errors here?

When processing the function call `d.foo(10)`, the compiler looks for `foo` in `Derived`. It finds one match there and it stops. It tries to use that function but the function's signature does not match the calling code. Hence, it is a compiler error.

When processing the function call `pb->foo()`, the compiler looks for `foo` in `Base`. It finds one match there and it stops. It tries to use that function but the function's signature does not match the calling code. Hence, it is a compiler error.

Once the compiler finds a `foo` in `Derived` it does not go searching for a matching `foo` in `Base`.

In this case, you can think of `Derived::foo` to be completely hiding `Base::foo`.

**Sample code 3:**

```
struct Base
{
   void foo()
   {
   }
};

struct Derive: public Base
{
   void foo()
   {
   }
   void foo(int )
   {
   }
};

int main()
{
   Derive d;
   d.foo();      // Resolves to Derived::foo()
   d.foo(10);    // Resolves to Derived::foo(int)

   Base *pb=&d;
   pb->foo();    // Resolves to Base::foo()
   pb->foo(10);  // Compiler error.

   return 0;
}
```

When processing the function calls `d.foo()` and `d.foo(10)`, the compiler looks for `foo` in `Derived`. It finds couple of matches there and it stops. Then it tries overload resolution. It is able to find a match for both versions.  Since neither of the `Derived::foo()`s is a `virtual` function, the binding is done at compile time.

When processing the function calls `bp->foo()` and `bp->foo(10)`, the compiler looks for `foo` in `Base`. It finds couple of matches there and it stops. Then it tries overload resolution. It is able to find a match for the first versions but not the second version. It generates an error for the second call.

Here `Derived::foo` not only hide `Base::foo` but also there are two overloaded versions of `Derived::foo`.

**Sample code 4:**

```
struct Base
{
   virtual void foo()
   {
   }
   void foo(int)
   {
   }
};

struct Derive: public Base
{
   void foo()
   {
   }
   void foo(int )
   {
   }
};

int main()
{
   Derive d;
   d.foo();      // Resolves to Derived::foo()
                 // But Derived:foo() gets called at run time.

   d.foo(10);    // Resolves to Derived::foo(int)
                 // But Derived:foo(int) gets called at run time.

   Base *pb=&d;
   pb->foo();    // Resolves to Base::foo()
                 // But Derived:foo() gets called at run time due to
                 // function overwritting.

   pb->foo(10);  // Resolves to Base::foo(10)
                 // Base:foo(int) gets called at run time.

   return 0;
}
```

This includes function hiding, function overloading, and function overwritting.

`Derived::foo` hides `Base::foo`.
`Derived::foo()` and `Derived::foo(int)` are overloaded.
`Base::foo()` and `Base::foo(int)` are overloaded.
`Base::foo()` is overwritten by `Derived::foo()`.

I hope that clears up some of your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You see this behavior because `foo()` is not declared as `virtual` in `Base`. In C++, member functions are non-virtual by default. You must explicitly declare a function as `virtual` in order to take advantage of dynamic dispatching and polymorphism.

Comment: Late to the party and used the wrong term... even correcting it doesn't make this a worthwhile answer.

Comment: But the extra explanation does.

Comment: @BenVoigt Late to the party by about two seconds. We were obviously answering at roughly the same time.

Answer (score 0):

There's no overloading or overwriting that's going on in this code. `Base::foo` is being called rather than `Derive::foo` because there hasn't been any specification by the programmer to use dynamic binding for the name `foo`. If the *virtual-specifier* isn't provided, the compiler finds the function based on the static type of the object on which it is called, rather than the type it may point to refer to. This is known as static binding, and it's done at compile-time.

If the virtual-specifer is used, the name of the function is looked up at runtime and called based on the runtime type of the object.

---

As an aside, your base class needs a virtual destructor for the same reason written above. If you have a `Base` class pointer that points to `Derive` deleting that pointer will only call the base class destructor rather than both the base and derived.

Comment: Um, no, the `Derived` destructor will destroy its base class subobject just fine. The point of virtual destructors is to ensure that the `Derived` destructor is called when `delete` is called on a pointer to `Base` that actually points to a `Derived`.